# How to delete node from xml based on attribute using java with DOM Parser

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I want to delete a node from XML file based on attribute using JAVA with DOM Parser.
For Example

```
<company>
    <staff id="1">
        <firstname>yong</firstname>

    </staff>
    <staff id="2">
        <firstname>low</firstname>

    </staff>
</company>
```

Based on staff id,i want to delete node.

Comment: I have tried following code after doing all docummentBuilder API. NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("staff");

for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
    
    Node node=nList.item(i);
    
    if (node.getNodeType()==Element.ELEMENT_NODE) {
     
     Element eElement=(Element) node;
     System.out.println(eElement.getAttribute("id"));
     if (eElement.getAttribute("id").equals("1")) {
      System.err.println("sdsd");
      node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
     }

   }
}

Comment: And - what happens? Do you get an exception or is the removed node still in the DOM?

Comment: No Exception.Node is still there in DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reply.
Above solution which i posted is correct.Only i need to write xml again with some transform API.
Posting solution,if any body has the same problem.

```
try{
                            //Save the Created XML on Local Disc using Transformation APIs as Discussed
                            TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                            Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
                            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                            Source s = new DOMSource(doc);
                            Result res = new StreamResult( new FileOutputStream(fXmlFile));
                            try {
                                transformer.transform(s, res);
                            } catch (TransformerException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        } catch(TransformerConfigurationException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                      } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                      }
```