# How to find Node attribute value and delete it in XML with Java DOM parser

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing

How can I find and delete item id="s2" using Java DOM parser?

```
<manifest>
    <item href="html/section1.html" id="s1" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
    <item href="html/section2.html" id="s2" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
    <item href="html/section3.html" id="s3" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
</manifest>
```

I use this code but return Null

```
Node metadataXML = doc.getElementsByTagName("manifest").item(0);
        NodeList list = metadataXML.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
            list.item(i).getAttributes().removeNamedItem("s2");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find difference way in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532519/how-to-delete-node-from-xml-based-on-attribute-using-java-with-dom-parser) links comment and worked

```
 NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
        for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nList.item(i);
            if (node.getNodeType() == Element.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) node;
                System.out.println(eElement.getAttribute("id"));
                if (eElement.getAttribute("id").equals("s" + index)) {
                    System.err.println("sdsd");
                    node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this answer: [Removing DOM nodes when traversing a NodeList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374088/removing-dom-nodes-when-traversing-a-nodelist)

You have to use something like:

```
Node metadataXML = doc.getElementsByTagName("manifest").item(0);
NodeList list = metadataXML.getChildNodes();
for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {

    Element manifestItem = (Element) list.item(i);
    if ("s2".equals(manifestItem.getAttribute("id"))) {
        metadataXML.removeChild(manifestItem);
    }

}
```

Comment: getAttribute("id")  method doesn't have in manifestItem. Only have getAttributes()

Comment: You have to cast it to Element first

Comment: Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to do it in vtd-xml, instead of DOM, you can find quite a few refereces on SO, even its own tag...

```
import com.ximpleware.*;

public class deleteNode {
    public  static  void main(String s[]) throws VTDException,java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException,java.io.IOException{
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        if (!vg.parseFile("input.xml", false))
            return;
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
        XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier(vn);
        ap.selectXPath("/*/*[@id='s2']");// this is the key XPath expression
        int i=0;
        while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){

            xm.remove(vn.getElementFragment());// remove the node
        }
        xm.output("new.xml"); // output to a new document called new.xml
    }

}
```